# Python script dow download JSON data and save as/convert to CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I am having trouble downloading data in a JSON format and converting it to a csv-file. In this case it is company overview data from alphavantage(https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo)

I can download the data with the following script:

```
import requests
import pathlib

solditems = requests.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo') # (your url)
pathlib.Path('data2.json').write_bytes(solditems.content)
```

Then I have to data on my local drive in the json format. But then I try to convert to JSON into a CSV and so far different methods have failed for me. I tried this method with pandas (https://datatofish.com/json-string-to-csv-python/) or this one (https://medium.com/@gabrielpires/how-to-convert-a-json-file-to-csv-python-script-a9ff0a3f906e) but I cant get any method to work. What would be the best way? I want a CSV-File with 2 lines. In the first line would be the keys like Symbol, Name, Decritpion etc and in the second line the values.

I just need a basic script to download JSON data and convert it to a CSV file. So I can parametrize it and build a loop around this process. But I am stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas does have a `json_normalize` method to do that. Or, the other option is you can construct the dataframe from json (dictionaries) as long as each dictionary is within a list, where each row in your table is represented by each element in the list.

Also note, you can use `.json()` on the request to store right away. No need to write to file localay and then convert to csv.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

solditems = requests.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=OVERVIEW&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo').json() # (your url)

df = pd.json_normalize(solditems)
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Or with the single dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([solditems])
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
  Symbol     AssetType  ... LastSplitFactor LastSplitDate
0    IBM  Common Stock  ...             2:1    1999-05-27

[1 rows x 60 columns]
```